# create dynamic replay to email address

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm creating a system using laravel for a very specific use. For each customer he will register a ticket, and for each ticket I would like to create an email address. This email address will be specific to that ticket, and will be used for "replay to". Whenever the "replay to" is answered, the system loads the message directly into the ticket.

I have no idea how to do this? How to create this email address?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1415724)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site for sub-contracting work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are propably looking for inbound email routes, and the easiest way is to use a third-party provider.

[Read this for example](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-inbound-email)